# I can't log in to gmail in ubuntu on an specific ISP

Tags: internet, gmail

It's weird that I have this problem just in Ubuntu not in windows.

I can't log in to gmail in Ubuntu at home (the specific ISP). But I can log in to gmail in Ubuntu (the same laptop) at the office.
I don't have any problem with gmail in windows at home or office, it just happen in Ubuntu at home.

I'm really curious what windows has that Ubuntu hasn't got? 
I tried both 13.10 and 14.04.

Nothing happenes after entering my username, password and verification.

EDIT: I disabled the 2 step verification. It doesn't have any effect on this problem.

EDIT2: I can visit other  sites. my problem is just with gmail. and i can log in using gmail in sites like askubuntu.com

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, maybe a stupid problem.... have you checked your keyboard settings? Try typing in your password in gedit or a terminal and see if the characters match.

Comment: no i'm sure about my passoword

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try disabling 2 step verification, then logging in. Who is your ISP at home and at the office?</strike>

Can you login via a [proxy](http://proxy4free.cf/)?

And what about other browsers, is this just Chrome(ium) or Firefox or all of them?

Comment: I'm in Iran. I don't think so you have info about ISPs that exist in Iran. BTW my ISP at home is ParsOnline and at office I think is TCT. and I'll let you know with disabling 2 step verification.
But why i don't have problem in Win?

Comment: I disabled 2 step verification. but nothing happens. still the same.

Comment: See my current edit.

Comment: no it does not related to browsers. I tried with all of them

Comment: and about proxy i didn't try it yet. I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

check **DNS settings**, try to resolve address, try **telnet** on 80 port, **traceroute** will do nice 
also try to disable firewall

Comment: I don't have problem with other sites.